# Automatically mount HDD partitions in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ubuntu-9.10, partitioning

I'm using Dell Latitude E5500 notebook and after crashing originally installed system (Vista Business 32bit) I began with Ubuntu.

Now I have my disc split into three partitions: win, data and ubuntu.  The first two are NTFS, last is EXT4.

When I start Rhythmbox all my mp3s located on DATA disc disappear, in Krusader i can't see it in `/media/` directory until I click `Places->DATA` and enter my password. After that songs appear in playlist and I can work with files there.

Please, how can I access those discs without this process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that the reason that you have to enter your password is because this is the first time that the data disc has been accessed and therefore it needs to be mounted.
I have the same issue and I just found [an article](http://maketecheasier.com/auto-mount-your-ntfs-partition-in-ubuntu/2009/04/14) that describes a process to automount an NTFS drive.

Comment: OK, partitions are mounted automaticaly. Thanks a lot :)